# python bluetooth discovery with pybluez

Tags: python, bluetooth

i am trying to run this script:

```
import PyOBEX
import bluetooth

print "performing inquiry..."

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True)

print "found %d devices" % len(nearby_devices)

for name, addr in nearby_devices:
    print " %s - %s" % (addr, name)
```

however i am getting a not implemented error in terminal. this is the out put that i get:

```
Last login: Sat Dec  4 20:59:06 on ttys001
You have mail.
cd '/Users/riceje7/School/NMD 430/' && '/usr/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/riceje7/School/NMD 430/BluetoohLocator.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
Joseph-Rices-MacBook-Pro:~ riceje7$ cd '/Users/riceje7/School/NMD 430/' && '/usr/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/riceje7/School/NMD 430/BluetoohLocator.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/riceje7/School/NMD 430/BluetoohLocator.py", line 2, in <module>
import bluetooth
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bluetooth/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
from osx import *
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/bluetooth/osx.py", line 3, in <module>
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

can anyone help me figure out what is going on and why the script won't run properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [source code for **init**.py](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/bluetooth/__init__.py) has

```
elif sys.platform == "darwin":
    from osx import *
```

And the [source code for osx.py](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/bluetooth/osx.py) is

```
from btcommon import *

raise NotImplementedError
```

This is consistent with the web page that only mentions Linux and Windows implementations.  You'll probably have to check with the developer about OSX support on their roadmap.