# pybluez installation errors on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, bluetooth, xcode5

I tried to install **pybluez** using following commands.

```
pip install pybluez

sudo easy_install pybluez
```

But for both commands I end up in errors.

**Environment:**

```
Mac OSX 10.9.1
Python 2.7
```

**Pip Logs :**

```
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c osx/_osxbt.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/osx/_osxbt.o

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'

osx/_osxbt.c:676:5: error: unknown type name 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef'; did you mean 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef'?

    IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef inquiry;

    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    IOBluetoothDeviceRef

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Headers/IOBluetoothUserLib.h:34:47: note: 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef' declared here

typedef struct OpaqueIOBluetoothObjectRef *                     IOBluetoothDeviceRef;

                                                                ^

osx/_osxbt.c:688:17: error: unknown type name 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef'; did you mean 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef'?

                IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef inquiryRef,

                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

                IOBluetoothDeviceRef

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Headers/IOBluetoothUserLib.h:34:47: note: 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef' declared here

typedef struct OpaqueIOBluetoothObjectRef *                     IOBluetoothDeviceRef;

                                                                ^

osx/_osxbt.c:703:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryCreateWithCallbackRefCon' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

    dd->inquiry = IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryCreateWithCallbackRefCon (&dd);

                  ^

osx/_osxbt.c:703:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'IOBluetoothDeviceRef' (aka 'struct OpaqueIOBluetoothObjectRef *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]

    dd->inquiry = IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryCreateWithCallbackRefCon (&dd);

                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

osx/_osxbt.c:705:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquirySetCompleteCallback' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

    IOBluetoothDeviceInquirySetCompleteCallback (dd->inquiry,

    ^

osx/_osxbt.c:717:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryStart' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

    IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryStart (dd->inquiry);

    ^

osx/_osxbt.c:721:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelete' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

    IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelete (dd->inquiry);

    ^

5 warnings and 2 errors generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /private/var/folders/f0/ldyq8xbx0fvckg001kk64j7r0000gn/T/pip_build_~...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/f0/ldyq8xbx0fvckg001kk64j7r0000gn/T/pip_build_~/pybluez/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/f0/ldyq8xbx0fvckg001kk64j7r0000gn/T/pip-j1ASQD-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/f0/ldyq8xbx0fvckg001kk64j7r0000gn/T/pip_build_~/pybluez
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 279, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1380, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 699, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/f0/ldyq8xbx0fvckg001kk64j7r0000gn/T/pip_build_~/pybluez/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/f0/ldyq8xbx0fvckg001kk64j7r0000gn/T/pip-j1ASQD-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/f0/ldyq8xbx0fvckg001kk64j7r0000gn/T/pip_build_~/pybluez


**easy_install Logs** 

Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pybluez/
Best match: PyBluez 0.20
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/PyBluez/PyBluez-0.20.zip#md5=79fad332df63b67a5f9a8d25042fb2a8
Processing PyBluez-0.20.zip
Running PyBluez-0.20/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-Y5Y9H1/PyBluez-0.20/egg-dist-tmp-kwjDlw

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'

**osx/_osxbt.c:676:5: error: unknown type name 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef'; did you mean
      'IOBluetoothDeviceRef'?**
    IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef inquiry;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    IOBluetoothDeviceRef

**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Headers/IOBluetoothUserLib.h:34:47: note:** 
      'IOBluetoothDeviceRef' declared here
typedef struct OpaqueIOBluetoothObjectRef *                     IOBluetoothDeviceRef;
                                                                ^
**osx/_osxbt.c:688:17: error: unknown type name 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef'; did you mean
      'IOBluetoothDeviceRef'?**
                IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef inquiryRef, 
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                IOBluetoothDeviceRef

**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Headers/IOBluetoothUserLib.h:34:47: note:** 
      'IOBluetoothDeviceRef' declared here

typedef struct OpaqueIOBluetoothObjectRef *                     IOBluetoothDeviceRef;

                                                              ^
**osx/_osxbt.c:703:19: warning: implicit declaration of function
      'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryCreateWithCallbackRefCon' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]**
    dd->inquiry = IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryCreateWithCallbackRefCon (&dd);
                  ^
**osx/_osxbt.c:703:17: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to
      'IOBluetoothDeviceRef' (aka 'struct OpaqueIOBluetoothObjectRef *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]**
    dd->inquiry = IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryCreateWithCallbackRefCon (&dd);


              ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
**osx/_osxbt.c:705:5: warning: implicit declaration of function
      'IOBluetoothDeviceInquirySetCompleteCallback' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]**
    IOBluetoothDeviceInquirySetCompleteCallback (dd->inquiry, 

   ^
**osx/_osxbt.c:717:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryStart' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]**
    IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryStart (dd->inquiry);
    ^

**osx/_osxbt.c:721:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelete' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]**
    IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryDelete (dd->inquiry);
    ^
5 warnings and 2 errors generated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any one able to install **pybluez** on **Mavericks** ?

On **Mountain Lion** also the same installation errors.

**Edit :**

Replaced IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef with IOBluetoothDeviceRef and got rid of the errors.
and able to install on Mac because of the warnings.

Installed using `sudo python setup.py install`

Here is the output

**running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyBluez-0.20-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyBluez-0.20-py2.7.egg-info**

When I tried to import bluetooth I got an exception

Here is the output

**>>> import bluetooth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "bluetooth/__init__.py", line 47, in 
    from osx import *
  File "bluetooth/osx.py", line 3, in 
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError**

Fllowing link mentioned about the error

[python bluetooth discovery with pybluez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359292/python-bluetooth-discovery-with-pybluez)

What should be done to install pybluez on Mac

Comment: Hi Mate, have you had any luck with that? I am hang the exact same issue. :(

Answer (score 6):

PyBluez is only for PC. Try lightblue

Download and install the master distribution: https://github.com/postskolkovo/lightblue-0.4

```
cd ~/Downloads/lightblue-0.4-master
sudo python setup.py install
```

If you get the error:

```
Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=$(NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL), VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64).

** INSTALL FAILED **
```

you'll have to open up setup.py and change:

```
os.system("xcodebuild install -arch '$(NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL)' -target LightAquaBlue -configuration Release DSTROOT=/ INSTALL_PATH=/Library/Frameworks DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES")
```

to:

```
os.system("xcodebuild install -arch 'i386' -target LightAquaBlue -configuration Release DSTROOT=/ INSTALL_PATH=/Library/Frameworks DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES")
```

via [this discussion](https://github.com/postskolkovo/lightblue-0.4/issues/7)

Answer (score 6):

It appears that the releases on PyPI are very outdated, but using the latest from the GitHub repository works perfectly.

#### Shell / Command Line

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez.git
```

#### requirements.txt

```
git+https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez.git
```

#### My Environment

- 2018 MacBook Pro
- Python 3.7.4
- MacOS Mojave (10.14.6)

Comment: I get the following error when I try to use the pybluez the way you suggested to install it: ImportError: Cannot load LightAquaBlue framework, not found at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightblue/LightAquaBlue.framework

Comment: that worked with me!

Answer (score 0):

A hint for getting pybluez installed;
BUT please note - I found this a few minutes ago and have yet to try it out...

```
$ python -m pip install pybluez2
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pybluez2
  Downloading pybluez2-0.46-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (191 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 191.1/191.1 kB 1.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pybluez2
Successfully installed pybluez2-0.46
```

INFO, if it matters:
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa) <-`$ source /etc/os-release; echo $NAME $VERSION`